# antlr4 - how to "override" a popMode?

Tags: antlr4

```
Lexer.g4

...
TEST: 'EXEC' -> pushMode (LG2)
...

mode LG2;

...
END_LG2: S_SEMICOLON -> type(S_SEMICOLON), popMode;
...
```

Most of the time LG2 is used as "island" languag.
But in some cases I would like to be able to also initiate directly the LG2 mode.
This I can achieve as followed:

```
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(...);
PL1Lexer lexer = new PL1Lexer(input);
lexer.pushMode(PL1Lexer.DB2);
```

The problem is that in that case I don't want the ';' to jump back to the other language.
So in short: how can I "stay" in the LG2 language if I directly start from there?
Is there a way to "override" the rule

```
END_LG2: S_SEMICOLON -> type(S_SEMICOLON), popMode;
```

by

```
ND_LG2: S_SEMICOLON -> type(S_SEMICOLON);
```

in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`Lexer.popMode()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#popMode()) method to use custom behavior. An option which does not require this would involve ANTLR 4.4.1's upcoming support for zero-length tokens.

```
mode LG2;

  // rules here

mode StayInLG2:

  ReturnToLG2
    : -> skip, pushMode(LG2)
    ;
```

You could then manually start in the `StayInLG2` mode. In response to popping back to the `StayInLG2` mode, the `ReturnToLG2` rule would not create a token or match any input, but it will push `LG2` back onto the mode stack.

```
PL1Lexer lexer = new PL1Lexer(input);
lexer.mode(StayInLG2);
lexer.pushMode(LG2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer looks nice, but the empty rule results in a warning that can't be suppressed:

```
non-fragment lexer rule ReturnToLG2 can match the empty string
```

So for a similar problem, I went with the override:

```
@members {
    @Override
    public int popMode() {
        return _modeStack.isEmpty()
            ? DEFAULT_MODE
            : super.popMode();
    }
}
```